# How to reduce spacing between 2 items on different lines in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I have few items in the same region. Is there a way that I can reduce the space between them ?

[image]

Regards,
Abha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set label to be displayed left of the item, not above it.

How? Instead of e.g. "Optional - Above", set it to "Optional"